# Write to terminal and buffer

Tags: php, console, io

```
/**
 * Execute an external program, display raw output in real-time, and buffer output pipes (stdout, stderr) for further processing.
 *
 * @param string|array $cmd Command to execute (not escaped)
 * @param string[] $output_buffers Buffers to capture
 * @return int Exit status code
 */
function tee($cmd, &...$output_buffers) {
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, array_fill(1, count($output_buffers), ['pipe', 'w']), $pipes);
    if($pipes) {
        $filePointers = [];
        foreach($pipes as $p => $pipe) {
            stream_set_blocking($pipe, 0);
            $filePointers[$p] = fopen("php://fd/$p", 'w');
        }
        foreach(array_keys($output_buffers) as $b) {
            $output_buffers[$b] = '';
        }
        $sleep = 10*1000;
        while($output_buffers) {
            $readSuccess = false;
            foreach(array_keys($output_buffers) as $b) {
                $p = $b+1;
                if(feof($pipes[$p])) {
                    fclose($pipes[$p]);
                    unset($pipes[$p]);
                    unset($output_buffers[$b]);
                } else {
                    $line = fgets($pipes[$b + 1]);
                    if(strlen($line)) {
                        $readSuccess = true;
                        fwrite($filePointers[$p], $line);
                        $output_buffers[$b] .= $line;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($readSuccess) {
                $sleep = 10*1000;
            } else {
                usleep($sleep);
                if($sleep < 150*1000) {
                    $sleep *= 2;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach($filePointers as $fp) {
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    return proc_close($proc);
}
```

I wrote this function because I write a lot of PHP-CLI scripts that interface with other shell programs. Often `passthru` works well for this, but sometimes you also want to capture `STDERR` in the event that the status code doesn't give enough information. This function lets you do that.

[This commenter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#89338) says that we have to put the pipes into non-blocking mode or the process can hang while it's waiting for you to read the other pipes, so that's what I've done.

Example usage:

```
tee("echo 'hello'; (>&2 echo \"error\"); echo 'world'", $stdout, $stderr);
dump($stdout);
dump($stderr);
```

Output:

```
hello
error
world
"""
hello\n
world\n
"""
"error\n"
```

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work so well. If a process asks for input, it'll just hang not display anything until you answer the question. Which is pretty weird, because this script works with `sleep` so I don't know why it wouldn't display the question.